# How Can I Configure a vNext Build Definition in TFS 2015 to Create a Work Item on Build Failure?

Tags: tfs, tfs-workitem, tfs-2015, build-definition

I think that I have found some missing functionality that I enjoyed with TFS 2013 XAML builds, that being that a failed CI build would create a Bug work item and assign it to the developer. Is this feature missing in TFS 2015 vNext? I've been searching in all the build steps and have yet to find it. If it is missing should I be waiting for an upgrade, or scripting myself in PowerShell, or is there some other better answer?

Answer (score 2):

You can find it under "Options" (second tab) when editing the build definition:

[image: Create work item on Failure]

Comment: Interesting. I don't see that. My version of TFS is 14.0.23128.0, which according to http://blogs.msdn.com/b/tfssetup/archive/2013/11/21/what-version-of-team-foundation-server-do-i-have.aspx is the RTM. Should I see that checkbox?

Comment: Must be an "Update 1" feature, I'm looking on VS Team Services and it's there now, I'm sure it's been there a while too.

Comment: I cannot find any mention of it anywhere in any release notes, but it might be part of this: https://www.visualstudio.com/news/tfs2015-update1-vs#xaml

Comment: I didn't find any mention there. My options tab only has the Multiconfiguration section.

Comment: Do you have any news on this? I can see this feature when using VisualStudio online, but not on my local TFS 2015.1 Server.

Comment: @Daniel 2015.2 RC is shipping soon, I'd guess it is in there.

Comment: Is part of 2015.2 RC2